# How to validate Telerik's RadSpinEditor when the value of the input change

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, input, telerik

I am using 2 RadSpinEditor WinForms controls. When one value is changed in any of the 2, I calculate the value of the second input.

The issue that I am running into is that, the value of the RadSpinEditor can change based on many things (for example, on keyDown, if a user changed the value using the up/down arrow or if the use type a non-numeric value the system auto correct it to the max value (i.e. 99.99))

How can I catch all these scenarios, to make sure they value are calculated immediately on value change.

Here is what I have done so far (the issue is that it does not change the value always)

```
private void InputMargin_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    double v = 0;
    try
    {
        double margin;
        double.TryParse(InputMarkup.Text, out margin);
        margin /= 100;
        v = Math.Round((margin / (1 + margin)) * 100, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
    catch
    {
        v = 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        InputMarkup.Text = v.ToString();
    }
}

private void InputMarkup_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    double v = 0;
    try
    {
        double markup;
        double.TryParse(InputMarkup.Text, out markup);
        markup /= 100;
        v = Math.Round((markup / (1 + markup)) * 100, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
    catch
    {
        v = 0;
    }
    finally
    {

        InputMargin.Text = v.ToString();
    }
}
```

I have also done this (which does not calculate at all - it seems that the ValueChanged event does not fire at all)

```
private void InputMargin_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    double v = 0;
    try
    {
        double margin;
        double.TryParse(InputMarkup.Text, out margin);
        margin /= 100;
        v = Math.Round((margin / (1 + margin)) * 100, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
    catch
    {
        v = 0;
    }
    finally
    {

        InputMarkup.Text = v.ToString();
    }
}

private void InputMarkup_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    double v = 0;
    try
    {
        double markup;
        double.TryParse(InputMarkup.Text, out markup);
        markup /= 100;
        v = Math.Round((markup / (1 + markup)) * 100, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
    catch
    {
        v = 0;
    }
    finally
    {

        InputMargin.Text = v.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Key Up event, you could use a Value Changed event which will fire whenever and however the value is changed. When you are entering the value using keyboard, the value changed event is fired after pressing the enter key.

I have tried it out. And it works for me.

You might get negative values in your calculation. So set minimum and maximum properties of your NumericUpDown control based on the range of the calculated value.

In your code, I have also noticed that you have events for both the controls. And in the event, you are changing the value of the other control. Why would you do that? This will cause both the events to fire one after the other.

Comment: I am using only one event either ValueChange or KeyUp